# Verification of completeness of $d_1 (x,y) = |\log x -\log y|$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A=(0,\infty) $ be a given set on which we define a  metric $d_1 (x,y)= |\log x -\log y| $. Prove that  $d_1$ is complete.

MY TRY: _____

Consider the usual distance on A by $d_2 (x,y)=|x-y|$. Clearly  $d_1 (x,y)= d_2 (f (x),f (y)) $ ,where $f (x)=\log x $. Thus $d_1$ and $d_2$ are isometric.  $d_2$ is not complete and as isometry preserves completeness  $d_1$ is also not complete.  So I have disproved what I had to prove. I found this problem in a textbook, so I guess the problem is correct and somehow I have done something wrong! But how! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you are making is that $f(x)=\log(x)$ is a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb R$. That means the isometry is an isometry between $(A,d_1)$ and ($\mathbb R,d_2)$, the latter being complete.

Comment: Sorry ! Now need to cry 